# Выбор всех классов в разных DOM

Tags: button, javascript, классы, dom

Подскажите пожалуйста, стоит задача с помощью JavaScript, **найти все ссылки с классом .button** и выполнить по ним действие (вызов модального окна). 
**querySelectorAll не помогает**, т.к. классы судя по всему находятся в различных DOM ветвях. Как быть? Есть какие-то хаки или может чего-то очень недопонимаю?

html к примеру такой:

```
<header>
    <a href="" class="button"></a>
</header>
<main>
    <a href="" class="button"></a>
    <a href="" class="button"></a>
    <a href="" class="button"></a>
</main>
<footer>
    <a href="" class="button"></a>
</footer>
```

JS

```
var link=document.querySelector(".button");
var popup = document.querySelector(".modal-window");
var close = document.querySelector(".close-form");

    link.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    popup.classList.add("modal-window-see");
    }, false);

    close.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    popup.classList.remove("modal-window-see");
    }, false);
```

Comment: > классы судя по всему находятся в различных DOM ветвях.

что, простите?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. судя по коду вы не дописали здесь кусок html
2. Вызывайте js код после формирования DOM дерева или заключайте его в функции наподобие window.onload или $(document).ready()
3. Вот немного перепилял код http://jsfiddle.net/Hr5Cn/1/

Comment: Спасибо, Mountpoint!
Ещё не очень разбираюсь в js, поэтому с трудом перевариваю даже такое. Как будет хватать очков поставлю +